# I get ImportError: No module named pyodbc when I try to connect to the sybase database

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, sap-ase

I am trying to connect to the sybase database using sqlalchemy. I am doing my development in Linux environment. I am also using python 2.7

I have the following code in which I am just trying to connect to the database. When I try run the piece of code with just the import part, I do not get the error `ImportError: No module named pyodbc`.

I only get the error with the import when I uncomment and run the `sal.create_engine` part of the code. I am not able to understand why it is saying the it is unable to import the pyodbc.

My code as of now:

```
import sqlalchemy as sal
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.connectors import pyodbc

# in order to connect, we need server name, database name we want to connect to
engine = sal.create_engine('sybase+pyodbc://dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database', echo = True)
conn = engine.connect()

# printing names of the tables present in the database
#print(engine.table_names())
```

May someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: `pyodbc` is a separate module.  Did you install it?

Comment: You don't need to do `from sqlalchemy.connectors import pyodbc` in your Python code but you *do* need to do `pip install pyodbc` from a command prompt in your virtual environment.

Comment: Note also that SQLAlchemy's internal `sybase` dialect is obsolete. You really should be using the external [sqlalchemy-sybase](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-sybase/) dialect (which I maintain).

Comment: @GordThompson I pip installed the pip install sqlalchemy-sybase as per the link. I am not getting the second step, "Create an ODBC DSN (Data Source Name) that points to your SAP ASE database".

Comment: Are you planning to use the SAP ASE ODBC driver, or will you be using FreeTDS ODBC? The former is preferred, but it is a bit more work to set up. Also, what is the name and version of the Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: @GordThompson This is the details of the linux distribution I am using. ```Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64``` Do I need to install this "SAP ASE ODBC driver"  and is it free? What is the latter approach?

Comment: You'll probably have to install the driver. I assume that it is available for free, given that I was able to download and install the entire SAP ASE Express Edition at no charge. On my sqlalchemy-sybase dev box the driver was installed as `/opt/sybase/DataAccess64/ODBC/lib/libsybdrvodb-sqllen8.so`

Comment: @GordThompson - question. What is the point of the sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc and sqlalchemy.connectors.pyodbc modules if you have to import pyodbc using pip? I'm trying to understand the point of those modules? Are they supposed to be internal?

Comment: @user2103050 - They control the particular behaviours when SQLAlchemy *interacts with* pyodbc. `sqlalchemy.connectors.pyodbc` manages behaviours that are applicable to pyodbc as a whole, while `sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc` tells SQLAlchemy how to behave when interacting with pyodbc *and* a SQL Server database.